# Stop workbox building service worker in webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, service-worker, workbox

I've just implemented Googles [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) tool to handle the creation of a service worker.

Using the `WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest()` within my webpack config was straightforward and the service worker registers nicely in the build. However, having the service worker during Dev is becoming a little bit of a pain and I want to be able to negate the service worker being built when using webpack in development mode and in webpack-dev-server, seemingly via some conditional build rules.

I've seen some suggestions online of webpacks `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` but having had a read around it a little I can't find any examples of using it in this circumstance. I was wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue and what their solution was?

Answer (score 2):

If it's having the SW run during development that is causing you problems, there a few options:

1. You could use Chrome DevTools "Bypass for network feature" to skip the service worker.

   [image]
2. Add an early return in your service worker that is stripped based on process.env.NODE_ENV or localhost origin.
3. In your client code, register / unregister based on process.env.NODE_ENV or localhost origin.
4. Otherwise, it might be worth raising an issue on [github.com/googlechrome/workbox](http://github.com/googlechrome/workbox).